# Using IActionResult with Azure Functions in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

After migrating my Azure Functions project to .NET 5, it has started wrapping my responses in a weird wrapper class.

For instance, consider the following endpoint:

```cs
public record Response(string SomeValue);

[Function("Get")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "get-something")]
    HttpRequestData request)
{
    return new OkObjectResult(new Response("hello world"));
}
```

Before, it would return:

```json
{
    "someValue": "hello world"
}
```

But now, it returns:

```json
{
  "Value": {
    "SomeValue": "hello world"
  },
  "Formatters": [],
  "ContentTypes": [],
  "DeclaredType": null,
  "StatusCode": 200
}
```

I get that it must be because it just tries to serialize the object result, but I can't find any documentation on how this is supposed to work in .NET 5.

My main function currently looks like this:

```cs
public static async Task Main()
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(x => 
            x.UseDefaultWorkerMiddleware())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, builder) => builder
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
            .Build())
        .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
        .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

My project is located here, in case someone are interested: https://github.com/sponsorkit/sponsorkit.io

Currently, my .NET 5 work is on a branch called `feature/signup-flow`.

Comment: Just return record not wrapped in OkResult

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Using IActionResult with Azure Functions in .NET 5?

You [can't return `IActionResult` with Azure Functions in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings). Or more generally, you can't return `IActionResult` with Azure Functions using the isolated process model. Quote from the docs:

> For HTTP triggers, you must use HttpRequestData and HttpResponseData to access the request and response data. This is because you don't have access to the original HTTP request and response objects when running out-of-process.

Instead of `IActionResult`, you need to return [`HttpResponseData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httpresponsedata). Example code is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/edfd70439e528ce5361d56d30bc22cad5723e03c/samples/Extensions/Http/HttpFunction.cs).

Comment: That seems like an insane compromise at first glance. Is there any way to work around this? I would really hate to lose all my strong-typing etc.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen: I'm not sure. I expect over time better supporting APIs will be available. The isolated process model for .NET is quite new right now ([one month](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916)). I haven't adopted it yet because I need durable functions, which are also not supported yet.

Comment: That's a pretty simplistic sample - just returning a string. What about objects and lists of objects? So you would have to deserialize any objects before sending?

Comment: @inliner49er: For now, yes. A lot of the ASP.NET pipeline helpers are not available yet. Things like serialization and content negotiation you have to build yourself.

Answer (score 10):

To return an object from .NET 5 Azure Functions, use the following code:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(obj);
return response;
```

Answer (score 4):

For those coming to this question in 2023, this can now be done by calling `ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()` rather than `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` in `Program.cs`. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#aspnet-core-integration)

Comment: I wonder if there is any advantage / disadvantage of using one over the other. Do you have more information about that?

Comment: You can't use any middleware pipeline stuff yet. You also can't customize your JsonSerializer options - see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1979

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Functions with .NET 7 we can just return the List or Object directly from the function and let the runtime handle the JSON serialization.

It might be necessary to adjust the global JSON settings to set camelCase etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

As per this ASP.NET Core article you can return IActionResult from .NET isolated function apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#aspnet-core-integration

You need to ensure you have the proper packages installed:

```xml
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
```

Comment: This is not possible in .NET 5, which is what was asked. It was added later.

Answer (score -1):

Was pleasantly surprised to find that returning Task from a "dotnet-isolated" function workins in Core 6.  Saved me a few hours as I do not need to change to Task in a number of functions

Answer (score -1):

After searching around and wanting to stay in the context of the IActionResult object, I ended up leveraging the ObjectResult object so that I can standardize all the service responses with the standardize JSON messages.