# How to return OkObjectResult without the extra stuff like Formatters?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, json-deserialization

When returning an OkObjectResult from my Azure Function like this:

```
    [Function("ReturnFoo")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReturnFoo([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
        HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
    object o = new
    {
        Foo = "bar"
    };

    return new OkObjectResult(o)
    }
```

It returns this JSON to the client:

```
 {
  "Value": {
    "Foo": "bar"
  },
  "Formatters": [],
  "ContentTypes": [],
  "DeclaredType": null,
  "StatusCode": 200
}
```

How can I return json that doesn't have all this extra stuff?
I simply want:

```
 {
  "Value": {
    "Foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

Or, even better, just:

```
  {
    "Foo": "bar"
  }
```

I know I can change my return type of my Azure Function to 'object', but I really want to return an IActionResult so that I can return other messages from this same function easily.

I have wasted a bunch of time trying to get this to work with custom JSonFormatters, and trying with JsonResult (which also has bloated properties on it) and it's not working and I suspect I am missing something really obvious and simple. Appreciate the support.

Comment: You can create your own class that implements `IActionResult` and return that

Comment: @stuartd I have tried, but I cant find any docs online of how to do the custom serilization? Can you point me to any?

Comment: @stuartd I am using .NET 7/Isolated.

Comment: Seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943858/how-do-i-return-json-from-an-azure-function ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return JSON from an Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943858/how-do-i-return-json-from-an-azure-function)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, thanks for sharing. Does this mean its not possible to do  this with IAsyncResult, and I need to use HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the use of Isolated function.  That's still a fairly new hosting model and answers are likely to be geared toward in-process if not specified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using IActionResult with Azure Functions in .NET 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045378/using-iactionresult-with-azure-functions-in-net-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET 5+ with Isolated functions, you are intended to use `HttpResponseData` which is a far more procedural way to return data.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings

Hopefully API's will improve in the future.

For a similar question, see: [Using IActionResult with Azure Functions in .NET 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045378/using-iactionresult-with-azure-functions-in-net-5)