# Upgrading Azure Function to .NET 7 and Runtime 4 - "No Job function found" "The scriptFile property is set to a file that does not exist"

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am trying to upgrade a .NET Core 3.1 Azure Functions v3 function to use .NET 7 and Azure Functions v4.

I am following the guide from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net7%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

Old .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

New .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.10.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.12.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have also created a `Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.Build();

host.Run();
```

But whenever I try to Debug through Visual Studio I am greeted with the following errors. I am not using Visual Studio Code.

> Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of
> [--csharp, --javascript]
>
> No job functions found. Try making  your job classes and methods
> public. If you're using extensions e.g Azure Storage, ServiceBus etc.)
> make sure you've called the registration method for the exteion in
> your startup code (e.g builder.AddAzureStorage() etc.)
>
> The 'User' function is in error: Invalid script file name
> configuration. The 'scriptFile' property is set to a file that does
> not exist.

All the functions are HTTP triggers so I don't believe I need to add any start-up code, plus I don't have any so where would this go?

Well the script file error makes sense as I can see the output file is looking for a DLL but with the upgrade not producing an .exe how on earth do I update this, these files are all generated by the compiler?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. To confirm I can create a new function from the template and run it without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK,

I can see you have migrated the Versions of NuGet Packages used in your .NET Core 3.1 to 7 Isolated from the `.csproj` file along with `Program.cs` file adding.

Even they are same Http Triggers but the function code is different.
There are lot of changes need to be made such as:

1. In .NET Core 3.1, the namespace looks like `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.*` but in .NET 7 Isolated Function Code, the namespaces will be `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.*`.
2. In Function Code - Function declaration section and also in the body - lot of changes need to be done when migrating from In-process to Out-of-process model such as Function Declaration attribute, Request object class and Response object class.

**.NET 7 Isolated Function Code Declaration**

```cs
[Function("HttpFunctionTrigger")]

public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req,

FunctionContext executionContext)

{
```

[image]

- In .NET 3.1 Function Code Declaration, `Function` Attribute will be `FunctionName`, `HttpRequestData` will be `HttpRequest`, `HttpResponseData` will be `OkObjectResult` and sample [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045378/using-iactionresult-with-azure-functions-in-net-5) given by @*StephenCleary*.
- Microsoft recommends upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to 6 (in-process) for easy upgrade process and then to .NET 7 Isolated model as specified in this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net7,azure-cli,windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#choose-your-target-net) of MS Doc.
- .NET Core 3.1 uses C# 8.0 Version and .NET 7.x uses the C# 11 language version so code should be converted accordingly.
- Also, not only the Project File, Packages Upgradation, Function Code needs to be changed accordingly and also `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` should be correct value like `dotnet-isolated` if it is .NET Core out-of-process model.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I completely forgot about the whole in-process / isolated stuff. I think for now my pass of least resistance is to go to .NET 6 and then review from there, thank you very much.